zoopla api registration web site box not allowed to be blank
Am setting up a program to webscrape from zoopla and am trying to register for a API key, but have realised that i need to enter a web site. Not sure what to put here, as i plan to run the code on just my computer as a personal project.
the part of the registration i am having an error with
should i try making a quick website just to enter here - have tried to find a similar porblemb but no one else seems to have had this issue before (may have an obvious answer, this is my first web-scraping project and first time trying to get an API key)

I've used my github account for similar api key requests; is that an option with zoopla?
